# UIDropInteraction iPad Air

Tags: ios, ipad, ios11

Trying to implement DragNDrop in my application.
Following code works for iOS 11 iPad Air 2, iPad Pro.

But **not working for iPad Air and iPad Air simulator**.

```
- (void) addDragAndDropToView:(UIView *) view {
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        UIDropInteraction * dropInteraction = [[UIDropInteraction alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
        [view addInteraction:dropInteraction];
    }
}
```

What is happening:
If everything ok I should receive

```
- (BOOL)dropInteraction:(UIDropInteraction *)interaction canHandleSession:(id<UIDropSession>)session
- (UIDropProposal *)dropInteraction:(UIDropInteraction *)interaction sessionDidUpdate:(id<UIDropSession>)session 
- (void)dropInteraction:(UIDropInteraction *)interaction performDrop:(id<UIDropSession>)session
```

callbacks.

And I'm receiving them on all devices except **Air** and **simulator of Air**.

Do you have some conclusions?

Comment: For me it isn't working in the iPad Air 2 simulator either as well as a real iPad Air.